# How do I format text in between xsl:text tags?

Tags: xslt, formatting

I have an xslt sheet with some text similar to below:

```
<xsl:text>I am some text, and I want to be bold</xsl:text>
```

I would like some text to be bold, but this doesn't work.

```
<xsl:text>I am some text, and I want to be <strong>bold<strong></xsl:text>
```

The deprecated b tag doesn't work either. How do I format text within an xsl:text tag?

Comment: BeerDNA, did you just edit this question to remove angle brackets showing wrong?

Comment: I'd forgotten to put the code tags around it and everything was garbled and the formatting was terrible for about the first 90 seconds of life. Apologize to those who clicked quickly and saw the garbage.

Comment: as just answered, it should be </strong>, both in the question and the accepted answer

Comment: You can check my answer here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59292527/3179207)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't. `xsl:text` can only contain text nodes and `<strong>` is an element node, not a string that starts with less-than character; XSLT is about creating node trees, not markup. So, you have to do

```
<xsl:text>I am some text, and I want to be </xsl:text>
<strong>bold<strong>
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
<fo:inline font-weight="bold"><xsl:text>Bold text</xsl:text></fo:inline>
```

- [XSL-FO Tutoria: Inline Text
  Formatting](http://www.ecrion.com/Support/Resources/XSL-FOTutorial/Inline.xml.html)
- [XSL-FO inline Object](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/obj_inline.asp)

Comment: The poster wanted to output a strong element, not use XSL FO. Besides that, this does not work. xsl:text can only create text nodes.

Comment: Well, poster didn't say anything about XSL:FO, but you're right xsl:text should be inside of fo:inline

Comment: This worked: <fo:inline font-weight="bold"><xsl:text>Catalog Number: </xsl:text></fo:inline>

Answer (score 3):

> <xsl:text **disable-output-escaping="yes"**>I want to be <strong>bold<strong> </xsl:text>

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this depends on how much formatting is needed in the content and also where you get content from.
If you have less content and less formatting then you can use what jelovirt suggested

```
<xsl:text>I am some text, and I want to be </xsl:text>
<strong>bold<strong>
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
```

However if your content has large formatting then what David Medinets suggests is better way to do it

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
```

We have some instructions to print on UI. The set of instructions is huge and of course we read those from XML file.

In such cases the above method is easy to use and maintain too. That is because the content is provided by technical writers. They have no knowledge of XSL. They know using HTML tags and they can easily edit the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

the correct way to use the strong tag is

```
<strong>This text is strong</strong>
```

not `<strong>` at the end

Here is the information reference: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp